# URLs com acentos

Tags: bug, status-futuro, acentuação

URLs com acentos não são reconhecidas integralmente e por isso o link pega apenas parte da URL. Exemplo: https://www.google.com.br/search?q=maçã

O trecho linkado é apenas
https://www.google.com.br/search?q=ma (quando visualizado no preview) ou https://www.google.com.br/search?q (na pergunta publicada)

Comment: `https://www.google.com.br/search?q=ma%C3%A7%C3%A3`

Comment: Resolver isso envolve mexer no parser de markdown, que é bastante trabalho. **Por enquanto**, melhor usar o botão de inserir link (`CTRL+L`), que faz a conversão dos caracteres especiais automaticamente